# Where to call time measurement for a method between inside the method itself or at the line that method is calling?

Tags: python, time

Where is the correct place to call time measuring between inside the method

```
def factorization(R, P, Q, K)
  start_time = timeit.default_timer()

  ...code...

  elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
  print elapsed
```

or when I call this method to execute?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

  ..code..

  start_time = timeit.default_timer()

  nP, nQ = factorization(R, P, Q, K)

  elapsed = timeit.default_timer() - start_time
  print elapsed
```

Is it significantly different? How?

Answer (score 1):

Call time measuring when invoke the method will be more accurate. Your function `factorization(R, P, Q, K)` should has return, you can not calculate the elapsed time after return, and the return should be also considered as the part code of the function.

Comment: I would also add that occasionally it is useful to profile just the profiler, or even the call overhead for an empty function. (Assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it away.). As to if it is significantly different? Likely nanoseconds or microseconds...but do something enough times and even microseconds add up.